# Can I use PHP array_search() to search for values that are themselves arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class containing a static array with string keys, with values that are arrays. I want to get the key for a particular array value, if there is one present.

I thought this code using array_search() would work, but it fails to find the value, it prints false. I thought that the "strict" parameter might make a difference, but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong? What's the best way to write the search code?

```
$ cat foo.php
<?php
class foo {
    static $name_to_bitnum = array(
        'Water Obstacle' => array('kind' => 'Facility', 'bitnum' => 5),
        'Driving' => array('kind' => 'Facility', 'bitnum' => 6),
        'Trails' => array('kind' => 'Facility', 'bitnum' => 7),
   );

    public static function bar($kind, $bitnum) {
        $search = array_search(array('kind' => $kind, 'bitnum' => $bitnum), self::$name_to_bitnum, $strict = false);
        // $search = array_search(self::$name_to_bitnum['Driving'], self::$name_to_bitnum, $strict = false);
        return $search;
    }
}
$foo = new foo();
echo var_dump($foo->bar('Driving', 6));
?>

$ php foo.php
C:\xampp1826\htdocs\OSH0\foo.php:21:
bool(false)
```

I note that if I uncomment the commented-out line, and use the value of the array element I'm looking for, by indexing into the array, then it succeeds and prints `string(7) "Driving"`. This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: According to your code, the two arguments are being passed to bar (Driving and 6).  Which turns `array('kind' => $kind, 'bitnum' => $bitnum)` into `array('kind' => 'Driving', 'bitnum' => 6)`. However, kind never equals Driving.

Comment: I think you've done what you want, if you get confused the output result, You used var_dump and it returns type and value, it's normal to print string(7) "Driving". But if you assign a variable and then echo it

Comment: @imvain2 My, how embarrassing! I actually just noticed this myself. Wonder if I should delete the question, or answer it myself and cite your comment as well...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @imvain2 in his comment, my testcase was passing 'Driving' to bar(), when it should have been passing 'Facility'. What a dope! Now I just have to go back to the original code to see why it was passing the wrong value. Very embarrassing, sorry for the noise.